# Array-based parameters check

Tags: javascript

I've got a simple JavaScript function that takes multiple types of arguments. Inside the function I'm doing a check on the arguments to determine which way the user called the function:

```
var build = function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
    var options = {
        to: {},
        from: {},
        relationship: null
    }

    if (_.isString(args[3]) && !_.isUuid(args[3]) && _.isString(args[4])) {
        options.to.type = args[3]
    } else if (_.isString(args[2]) && !_.isUuid(args[2]) && _.isString(args[3])) {
        options.to.type = args[2]
    }
}

// called like:
build(client, dataObj, 'relationship', 'type', 'name')
// or
build(client, dataObj, 'relationship', '<uuid>')
```

This looks messy and isn't really scalable. Is there a more succinct way I can write this (perhaps using `.map()`, `.filter()`, or `.reduce()`)?

Comment: This looks hypothetical to me. `to.type`? `args`? Is this real code, or is this example code?

Comment: Real code. `args` being an array of arguments to the function from `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)`.

Comment: Okay. However, as it stands, it looks hypothetical. Perhaps if you included more code, such as (at least) the beginning of the function along with this `options` object, you may see some better feedback.

Comment: Alright, I did that. Frankly it's not a difficult bit of code, I just would like to write it more cleanly if there's a way.

Comment: Thanks! Your post looks much better now. I understand its fairly simple code, but if we see the full scope, perhaps better alternatives can be proposed.

Comment: Not a full answer but: if each arity of your function takes a different parameter set, can you just check the length of `args` and proceed from there? Eg. if 4 params, assume the 4th is a uuid, etc.?

Comment: Nope, sometimes the args length is the same but types are different. E.g. If it's a uuid vs plain string I need to do something differently. There is also some validation that throws an error if the wrong type is passed.

Comment: please add to your question the complete list of _legal_ combinations of types that you are expecting in the `arguments`.  The only difference between the two branches that I can see is a difference of -1 in the array offsets that can potentially be avoided by removing the extra element, but  I can't tell from the information provided the circumstances where that's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the functions that correspond to a given argument configuration separately:

```
const processStringNumber = (string, number) => console.log(number + ' is a number')
const processStringString= (string, string2) => console.log(string2+ ' is a string')
```

Put the argument configurations and the corresponding functions in a data structure:

```
const processingObj = [
  {
    argsTypes: ['string', 'number'],
    process: processStringNumber
  },
  {
    argsTypes: ['string', 'string'],
    process: processStringString
  }
]
```

Write a helper that does the checks and dispatches the corresponding function:

```
//Retrieve the types of an array of args (can have different implementations)
const getTypes = (args) => args.map((arg) => typeof arg)

//Calls the appropriate function from 'processingObj'
const process = (args, processingObj) =>
  processingObj
    .find((process) => _.isEqual(process.argsTypes, getTypes(args)))
    .process(...args)
```

Usage:

```
process(["aaa", 1], processingObj) // 1 is a number
process(["aaa", "aaa"], processingObj) // aaa is a string
```

Here is also an [ES5 version (via Babel)](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=const%20processStringNumber%20%3D%20(string%2C%20number)%20%3D%3E%20console.log(number%20%2B%20'%20is%20a%20number')%0D%0Aconst%20processStringString%3D%20(string%2C%20string2)%20%3D%3E%20console.log(string2%2B%20'%20is%20a%20string')%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20processingObj%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20argsTypes%3A%20%5B'string'%2C%20'number'%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20process%3A%20processStringNumber%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20argsTypes%3A%20%5B'string'%2C%20'string'%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20process%3A%20processStringString%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2FRetrieve%20the%20types%20of%20an%20array%20of%20args%20(can%20have%20different%20implementations)%0D%0Aconst%20getTypes%20%3D%20(args)%20%3D%3E%20args.map((arg)%20%3D%3E%20typeof%20arg)%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2FCalls%20the%20appropriate%20function%20from%20'processingObj'%0D%0Aconst%20process%20%3D%20(args%2C%20processingObj)%20%3D%3E%0D%0A%20%20processingObj%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.find((process)%20%3D%3E%20_.isEqual(process.argsTypes%2C%20getTypes(args)))%0D%0A%20%20%20%20.process(...args)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0Aprocess(%5B%22aaa%22%2C%201%5D%2C%20processingObj)%20%2F%2F%201%20is%20a%20number%0D%0Aprocess(%5B%22aaa%22%2C%20%22aaa%22%5D%2C%20processingObj)%20%2F%2F%20aaa%20is%20a%20string)

Comment: Thanks Bobby - would be great to have a non ES6 option too?

Comment: Added a comment

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot. I like that solution.